# Check multiple mail accounts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a simple python code that check how many mails in a mailbox. But if I want it to check two or more mail-accounts at the same time. How can this be done?

Code so far:

```
from imapclient import IMAPClient

name = 'name_of_account_1'
username = "username@domain.onmicrosoft.com"
password = 'password'

imap_server = "outlook.office365.com"

client = IMAPClient(imap_server, ssl=True)
client.login(username, password)

client.select_folder("INBOX", readonly=True)
result = client.search()
print(f"{name}: {len(result)}")

client.logout()
```

This output for example:

```
name_of_account_1: 18
```

But I would like to check for account_2 and account_3 at the same time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code in a function:

```py
from imapclient import IMAPClient

def check_mail(args):
    name, username, password, imap_server = args
    client = IMAPClient(imap_server, ssl=True)
    client.login(username, password)

    client.select_folder("INBOX", readonly=True)
    result = client.search()
    client.logout()
    return dict(name=name, unread=result)
```

And then run multiple instances of the function in separate threads:

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

NPROC = 6 # max number connections
pool = Pool(NPROC)
tasks = (
         ("google", "me@gmail.com", "pass1", "imap.gmail.com"),
         ("example", "me@example.com", "pass2", "imap.example.com"),
        )

results = pool.map(check_mail, tasks)
for result in results:
    print(f"{result['name']} had {result['unread']} unread messages")
pool.close()
```

Note that I've used threads here (`multiprocessing.dummy`) rather than processes, as the code is not cpu bound, and that I've factored the `check_mail` functions slightly awkwardly to make passing arguments a bit easier.

For more information, check out the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) docs.